# Databinding custom objects

Tags: wpf, binding, observablecollection

```
    public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // Private Properties
        private string _name;
        private List<string> _address;

        // The Public properties for which the getters and setters are implemented appropriately (raising OnPropertyChanged event)
    }

    public class EmployeeRecords: ObservableCollection<Employee>
    {
        public bool AddEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            Add(employee);
            return true;
        }

        public bool RemoveEmployee(int index)
        {
            if (Count > 0)
            {
                RemoveAt(index); // is the same as doing 'RemoveAt(SelectedIndex);'
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    **XAML:**

<Window x:Class="EmployeeInfo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:EmployeeInfo"
        Name="Page1" Height="225" Width="610"
        Title="DATABINDING DEMO">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EmployeeTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EmpId}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Designation}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <src:EmployeeRecords x:Key="EmpInfo"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>

        <Binding Source="{StaticResource EmpInfo}"/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Canvas Height="190" Width="600">
        <Label Name="lblName" Height="30" Width="50" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" >Name</Label>
        <TextBox Name="txtBoxName" Height="30" Width="125" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="60"  />

        <Label Name="lblEmpId" Height="30" Width="50" Canvas.Top="40" Canvas.Left="0" >EmpId</Label>
        <TextBox Name="txtBoxEmpId" Height="30" Width="50" Text="{Binding Path=EmpId}" Canvas.Top="40" Canvas.Left="60"  />

        <Label Name="lblDesignation" Height="30" Width="50" Canvas.Top="75" Canvas.Left="0" >Designation</Label>
        <TextBox Name="txtBoxDesignation" Height="30" Width="50" Text="{Binding Path=Designation}" Canvas.Top="75" Canvas.Left="60"  />

        <Label Name="lblAddress" Height="30" Width="50" Canvas.Top="115" Canvas.Left="0" >Address</Label>
        <TextBox Name="txtBoxAddress" Height="30" Width="50" Text="{Binding Path=Address}" Canvas.Top="115" Canvas.Left="60" />
        <TextBox Name="txtBoxAddress2" Height="30" Width="50" Text="{Binding Path=Address}" Canvas.Top="115" Canvas.Left="120" />

        <Button Height="30" Width="50" Canvas.Top="155" Canvas.Left="0" Content="Update" Click="UpdateButton_Click"/>
        <Button Height="30" Width="50" Canvas.Top="155" Canvas.Left="60" Content="Submit" Click="SubmitButton_Click"/>
        <Button Height="30" Width="50" Canvas.Top="155" Canvas.Left="120" Content="Remove" Click="RemoveButton_Click" />

        <ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" 
                 MouseDoubleClick="LstEmployee_MouseDoubleClick" Name="lstEmployee" Height="180" Width="190" 
                 Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="200" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EmployeeTemplate}"/>

        <ListBox Name="listAddress" Height="180" Width="190" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="400" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=/Address}"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs:
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private EmployeeRecords _empRecords;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Initialize();

            lstEmployee.ItemsSource = _empRecords;
        }
      .
      .
      .
      .
    }
```

I'm trying to display all the properties of Employee in the 1st listBox and just the addresses in the 2nd ListBox. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

Since I can't explicitly access the Employee object within EmployeeRecords, how can I bind the Address list inside of Employee to a control?

Thanks in advance!
Shanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to display the address of the selected Employee in the second `ListBox`, the following should work.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="listAddress" Height="180" Width="190" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="400" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lstEmployee, Path=SelectedItem.Address}"/>
```

Note:

I have assumed that the public property name for the backing field `private List<string> _address;` is `Address`